# How to programmatically add custom markup to every displayed user name

Tags: 8, theming, users

Drupal 8.x

I am currently using [hook_preprocess_user()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess/8.5.x).

I would like to alter the username to add some custom markup to every username.

**MYMODULE.module:**

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_user(&$variables) {
  $variables['elements']['#user']->name->value = t('Name @newMarkup', ['@newMarkup' => ' Hello']);
}
```

This returns `Name Hello Hello`. Concatenation adds 'Hello' twice so this approach is not working.

I've also worked with [user_format_name_alter(&$name, $account)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_format_name_alter/8.5.x), however, this does not seem to fit my use case.

How can I alter the username text? Not looking for a "currentUser" solution, but every user so names are changed everywhere. Reference, Views, etc.

Comment: In a views preview at `/admin/structure/views/view/view_name` and a views page, it appears to render ok. I have been testing via a referenced views block.

Answer (score 3):

Seems [`hook_user_format_name_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_format_name_alter/8.5.x) is your best bet. But same as in the other answer markup doesn't seem to be allowed everywhere. Normally the user name is only allowed to be a string.

The following won't work for Views for example. It will print just a string.

```
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup;

/**
 * Implements hook_user_format_name_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_user_format_name_alter(&$name, $account) {

  $name = new TranslatableMarkup('@name <span class="foo-bar">Foo Bar</span>', ['@name' => $name]);
}

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYMODULE_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {

  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'entity.user.canonical') {

    $name = $variables['title']['#markup']->__toString();
    $variables['title'] = new TranslatableMarkup('@name <span class="foo-bar">Foo Bar</span>', ['@name' => $name]);
  }
}
```

So, what I'd recommend now is, you maybe take the `*_preprocess_page_title` hook – as this is working just fine on user pages – and for all other places (references, Views etc.) you maybe create a new custom formatter or pseudo field to do the job.

Comment: +1 ^. I've noticed a lot of different implementations of the "username". For example a view of users displaying fields, and the field username. If you link that field to the user it will use `username.html.twig` template, if you do not link the field it uses `views--field.html.twig` template. So far it seems whether with preprocess or template overrides, you need multiple implementations to get all username instances... The other side of the problem is that `hook_preprocess_user()` gets rendered multiple times in some instances.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;

// Updating a user is a three step process:
// 1) load the user object to change
// 2) set property/field to new value
// 3) Save the user object.

// This example updates the user name.

// $uid is the user id of the user user update
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($uid);

// Don't forget to save the user, we'll do that at the very end of code.

// Modify username
$username = $user->getUsername();
$username .= " Hello";
$user->setUsername($username); // string $username: The new user name.

// The crucial part! Save the $user object, else changes won't persist.
$user->save();

// Congratulations, you have updated a user!
```

I based this on the examples in this Github gist:

https://gist.github.com/dreambubbler/671afd7f962ae46687e41340b396d266

Comment: Seems you are actually recommending to fetch all users and re-save them with an updated user name. In a batch maybe, on `hook_update_N`? And this doesn't append markup. Only strings seem to be allowed.

Comment: Good point -- this is wrong. The question is just how to alter the markup, not the actual user object. So this doesn't answer the question at all. Hopefully someone else can do a better job! (I'll just leave this here rather than deleting it, because it does something interesting and somewhat related.)